# Custom Actions not been called

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.6

I have some problems with managed code custom actions. I have 3 custom actions but only one of them is working. They are called at different times in InstallExecuteSequence but moving them makes no difference. I know there not getting very far because if I place a message box at the beginning of the routine(for debugging) it never get called . Where am I going wrong ? The actions are created like so.

```
<Binary Id="CA" SourceFile="$(var.ca.Custom.Actions.TargetDir)$(var.ca.Custom.Actions.TargetName).CA.dll" />
         <CustomAction Id="WriteRemoveArpEntry" Property="CustomActionData" Value="PNAME=$(var.ProductName)" HideTarget="yes" />
    <CustomAction Id="RemoveArpEntry" BinaryKey="CA" DllEntry="RemoveProductFromARP" Return="ignore" />

    <CustomAction Id="SetValueforProductFolder" Property="CustomActionData" Value="SDIR=[INSTALLDIR];TDIR=[MANUDIR]\backup\$(var.ProductName)\$(var.VersionNumber)" HideTarget="yes" />
    <CustomAction Id="Backup_Product_DIR" BinaryKey="CA" DllEntry="BackupDIR" Return="ignore" />

   <CustomAction Id="WriteInstallAttemptData" Property="CustomActionData" Value="PRODUCTNAME=$(var.ProductName);APPVERSION=$(var.VersionNumber)" HideTarget="yes" />
    <CustomAction Id="WriteInstallAttempt" BinaryKey="CA" DllEntry="WriteXMLServer" Return="ignore" />
```

I then call them here

```
  <Custom Action="SetValueforProductFolder" Before="Backup_Product_DIR">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
  <Custom Action="Backup_Product_DIR" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
  <Custom Action="WriteRemoveArpEntry" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
  <Custom Action="RemoveArpEntry" After="WriteRemoveArpEntry">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
  <Custom Action="WriteInstallAttemptData" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
  <Custom Action="WriteInstallAttempt" After="WriteInstallAttemptData">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>

 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The headers for the routines look like this

```
public static ActionResult BackupDIR(Session session)
   {


public static ActionResult RemoveProductFromARP(Session session)
   {

Public static ActionResult WriteXMLServer(Session session)
    {
```

However only WriteXMLServer works. In the log file I get the following .

> MSI (s) (BC:9C) [07:23:45:562]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSI2E2A.tmp, Entrypoint: BackupDIR CustomAction
>   Backup_Product_DIR returned actual error code 1154 but will be
>   translated to success due to continue marking

In the one that works I get

> MSI (s) (BC:A0) [07:24:25:994]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSICC20.tmp, Entrypoint: WriteXMLServer SFXCA:
>   Extracting custom action to temporary directory:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSICC20.tmp-\ SFXCA: Binding to CLR version
>   v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was very simple I forgot the

```
[CustomAction]
```

For the other two routines.